# How to avoid basic get url structure in php get method

Tags: php, url, get

I want to use GET method in php. it will be like "www.example.com/test.php?id=1". But how can I avoid this structure and using something like www.example.com/test/id or any other structure?

Please below is my .htaccess file. Can anyone tell what should I add in this? And how can I use that get value in PHP?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You can use mod_rewrite for that.

Comment: But how? Please explain

Comment: Have a look at http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

Comment: Just Google "mod_rewrite" and look at the link Ross included above.

Comment: This is [a very popular question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+htaccess+routing) here.

Comment: @MarcB - a new impressive super-power: close as duplicate on your own? `:)`

Comment: @halfer: Indeed. that's odd. never happened before...

Comment: Alright @Marc, well as long as you remember you probably still can't fly, you'll be fine.

Comment: I don't always downvote duplicate questions, but I certainly do when such a question gets a sympathy upvote. To anyone with the rep to upvote: please don't _encourage_ off-topic/dup questions!

Comment: I use my website in subdomain. So should I create a .htaccess file inside that folder?